# "Deprecated: parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated in"

Tags: php, string, parsing, url

I want to run the following command with exec but I am getting an error. So what should I use instead?

```
 php /var/.../../example.php -- 123456789 exampleData1 exampleData2
```

Error:

```
Deprecated: parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated in /var/.../../example.php on line X
```

I tried this:

```
$argumentsArray = [
    'postID' => 123456
    'foo' => 'bar'
];

exec(php /var/.../../example.php -- $argumentsArray);
```

and;

```
 parse_str(parse_url($argv[0], PHP_URL_QUERY),$arguments);
 $postID = $arguments['postID'];
```

Error: `Notice: Undefined index: postID in..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't substitute an entire array into a string. Use `implode()` to convert an array into a string with a delimiter between the values.

```
$argumentsArray = [
    'postID' => 123456
    'foo' => 'bar'
];

$arguments = implode(' ', $argumentsArray);

exec("php /var/.../../example.php -- {$arguments}");
```

Comment: I guess there is no way to just send `argumentsArray`. For example; `example.php -- $argumentsArray $argumentsArraySecond ` ?

Comment: You could use `implode(' ', $argumentsArray)` to make a string out of the array values.

Comment: But I thought you wanted to just get the `postID`, like you did with `$postID = $arguments['postID'];`

Comment: The question is very unclear about what you really want to do. Your example says `exampleData1` but `$argumentsArray` contains `bar`, so it wasn't obvious that the other elements of the array mapped to the command arguments.